# Format timedelta using string variable

Tags: python, python-2.6

Using Python 2.6

Given the following line of code, how can I dynamically build the value for timedelta from variables in a DB?

```
next_alert_date = datetime.strptime(start_due_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(days=2)
```

Basically, I need something like this but it doesnt appear to work.

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
next_alert_date = datetime.strptime(start_due_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + timedelta(%s=%d) % (interval_type, interval_num)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you're misunderstanding `%` operator used for [string formatting operation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#string-formatting); it is used to make a string.

```
>>> 'timedelta(%s=%d)' % ('days', 2)
'timedelta(days=2)'
```

Use [`**` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to  pass keyword arguments dynamically:

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(**{'days': 2})
datetime.timedelta(2)

>>> interval_type = 'days'
>>> interval_num = 2
>>> datetime.timedelta(**{interval_type: interval_num})
datetime.timedelta(2)
```

Comment: Ah Ok... sorry Python newbie here. :-) Works perfectly, thank you.